# UITableViewCell super class property returning nil when set from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subclass

I've burned a lot of time on this. A property (`isSender`) of a master/super class of UITableViewCell is always returning nil when the property is set from the tableView:

Here's the master Cell Class:

```
   class MasterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var userProfileImage:UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var postTextLabel:UILabel!

    var isSender:Bool!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
// code here
    }
```

Here's the Cell Subclass:

```
class VideoPostTableViewCell: MasterTableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()



    if isSender == true {
        print("true")
    }
    else {
        print("false")
    }
```

Here's the `tableView` method:

```
func configureCell(indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoPostTableViewCell") as? VideoPostTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()}

        let x = post.userID
        let y = user?.uid
        let isEqual = (x == y)
        cell.isSender = isEqual
        return cell
```

`isSender` always returns `nil`

Of note: `nil` is also returned when I set it `isSender` directly in `VideoPostTableViewCell`. Additionally, when I put a break point at `let isEqual = (x == y)` , `isEqual` returns `true`

Last, there are other properties in `VideoPostTableViewCell` and `MasterTableViewCell` that are all set properly with the same method in `tableView`. I've left them out of the question to reduce code.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So it always prints `false`?

Comment: correct, isSender always returns nil and thus it prints 'false'. However, I know isEqual (in the tableView method setting it)  returns true.

Comment: You are evaluating `if isSender == true` inside `awakeFromNib()` ... that happens before you execute `cell.isSender = isEqual`.

Comment: Could you print `isSender` after `cell.isSender = isEqual`

Comment: DonMag - Yes, if I add a class method in MasterTableViewCell to set isSender in conigureCell in tableView, I get the Bool set properly. Thank you!

Comment: Please mention where in code are you setting `isSender`, other than as mentioned in _Of note_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP's comment...

The evaluation of `if isSender == true` is taking place inside `awakeFromNib()`, but that is happening ***before*** the execution of `cell.isSender = isEqual`.

Answer (score 0):

In your guard statement you should fix the else case:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoPostTableViewCell") as? VideoPostTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Misconfigured cell type, VideoPostTableViewCell!")
}
```

Comment: I think the application will crash on `return VideoPostTableViewCell()`, author did not mentioned it in question.

Comment: I've changed it to crash on purpose to be safer